# How to train neural network with big data set in R using neuralnet?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I have data.table in r with 150 000 rows in it. 
I use 9 features and it's training time more than 30 mins, I didn't wait more. 
Also tried it on 500 rows (it takes 0.2 sec) and on 5000 it takes (71.2 sec).
So how I should train my model with all data or may be you can give me any other advice?

here compile log:

```
train1 <- train[1:5000,]+1
> f1 = as.formula("target~ v1+ v2+ v3+ v4+ v5+ v6+ v7+ v8+ v9")
> a=Sys.time()
> nn <-neuralnet(f1,data=train1, hidden = c(4,2), err.fct = "ce", linear.output = TRUE)
Warning message:
'err.fct' was automatically set to sum of squared error (sse), because the response is not binary 
> b=Sys.time()
> difftime(b,a,units = "secs")
Time difference of 71.2000401 secs
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for! In MATLAB, NN Toolbox takes care for almost everything such as, normalizing data, removing missing and constant values, dividing data into segments for training, validation, and testing. You usually don't need BIG data and you also can take a sample for training / validation and another sample for testing etc. Also different transfer functions and different learning algorithm might be used for approximation / regression or classification.

Comment: MXNet is the best R package I have found for training neural networks: http://myungjun-youn-demo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/R-package/

Comment: thank you will try it package.

Answer (score 1):

This is to be expected in my experience, there are a lot of calculations involved in Neural Nets. I personally have one written in Python (2 hidden layers), detailed including momentum term, I have about 38,000 patterns of 56 inputs and 3 outputs.  Splitting them into 8,000 chunks took about 10 minutes to run and just under a week to learn to my satisfaction.

The whole set of 38,000 had a larger hidden nodes to store all the patterns and that took over 6 hrs to go through one cycle and over 3 months to learn.  Neural Networks is a very powerful tool but it comes at a price in my experience, others may have better implementation but all the comparisons of classification algorithms I have seen, have always mentioned the time to learn as being significant.